# Serverless Outbound traffic protection

Tags: node.js, security, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Our team is currently working on an Web API that runs in ExpressJS and is deployed via Google Cloud Functions. We've moved beyond our core MVP deliverable and now have time to beef up more of our security/logging features.

Being paranoid (as you should be when developing security) I would like to protect our api from malicious code introduced from one of our npm packages.

I understand that there are many attacks possible if this were to happen. But I would like to protect against the class that send information to the attackers server.

Is there a way to monitor/whitelist all outbound requests? Perhaps by wrapping the Node process itself or utilizing a feature created by Google.

Thank you very much for reading my question, and stay safe!

Answer (score 0):

This is late, obviously, but I still think it's a relevant question that probably many (should!) think about.

We've had a bit of experience with [Puresec Function Shield](https://www.puresec.io/function-shield) which works for AWS Lambda and apparently also Google Cloud Functions. One of its features is in fact about blocking outbound network traffic.

You should also be able to put your function in a VPC and set its firewall rules to disallow any traffic that is not conformant to your own known ports and sources.

Hope that helps any late-comers into this question.